# How would you go about persisting selectors in links in CQ5 / AEM

Tags: aem, sling

I am trying to keep particular selectors present within links when hitting a cq5 page.

For example, say you have gone to /content/mysite/mypage.stickyselector.html, I want all of my subsequent links on the page, such as the aboutus.html and contact.html pages to keep the aboutus.stickyselector.html and contact.stickyselector.html links.

There are a few reasons I'm trying to do this, including preventing excessive rewrites when mobile devices hit, such as mypage.smart.html, as we can let the rewrite rules allow the user to go through without redetection of device type, as well as any customised content etc.

I have tried creating my own Link Rewriting Transformer, which is fantastic for rewriting links where you have all of the information at hand, however, I don't seem to be able to obtain the selectors used to get to the page containing the links at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. Rewrite the urls on the outbound response in CQ (as suggested by David)
2. Rewrite the urls on the inbound request using mod_rewrite at dispatcher (assuming Apache)

As David covered scenario 1, I'll describe the second scenario

The "sticky" selector value can be returned in a cookie to the client

```
Set-Cookie: selector=stickyselector;
```

Each subsequent request to the site from the client will contain that cookie.  You can then use that cookie to rewrite in the URL in apache before it gets presented to the dispatcher module (and eventually the publish instance:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} selector=([^;]+) [NC]    # If we have the selector cookie
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.%1.html [PT]           # add it to the request url before extension
```

So a request that arrives at the dispatcher looking like this:

```
GET /content/mysite/mypage.html HTTP/1.1
Cookie: selector=stickyselector;
```

Would arrive at the publish instance rewritten as:

```
/content/mysite/mypage.stickyselector.html
```

If you are using this approach for device/channel specific renditions then you *could* alternatively use the user agent value instead of a cookie to drive selector addition.  For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipod|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.mobile.html [PT]              # add channel selector to the request url
```

Positives of this approach are that all users are presented with the same URL (e.g./content/mysite/mypage.html) the selectors in URLs are only presented to CQ.

Negatives are that it normally would require cookies and it depends on apache configuration.

Comment: Neat! Will definitely give this one a go. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the sling request, you can get a [string of all the selectors](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/request/RequestPathInfo.html#getSelectorString%28%29) with:

```
String selectors = slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectorString();
```

Comment: & you can use `getSelectors()` alternatively to get a `String[]` of the selectors (you might only want to persist selectors that you expect rather than any that are there).

Comment: Unfortunately, getting the slingRequest seems to be the problem. This is in the Link Rewriting Transformer, so it seems a bit far down the rabbit hole, unless if I'm missing something. On another note, it seems as though selectors *should* actually be retained automatically with a mobile device, however, we must have a setting misconfigured or something. Will post when I know more.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the rewriting pipeline. Have you considered the following:

```
public class YourTransformer implements Transformer {
    protected SlingHttpServletRequest request;
    String selectors = "";

    public void init(ProcessingContext context, ProcessingComponentConfiguration config) throws java.io.IOException { {
        request = context.getRequest();
        String[] _selectors = request.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectors();
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        for (String _selector : _selectors) {
            buff.append(".").append(_selector);
        }
        selectors = buff.toString();
    }

    // rest of the methods go here
}
```

now when you rewrite links, you have your selector string ready to go.

Comment: Hey Kaiser, that's a great solution. I will certainly be taking this approach for a non-cookie solution. The previous answer suggesting the apache rewrite is the solution we are going with, but thanks so much for responding. Just getting the context out in the transformer will solve another problem I've been having.

Comment: @BayaniPortier glad i could help :) one sad thing i found out was that the htmlgenerator service in cq was super buggy. on full-page renders, only a fraction of html events were generated (e.g. "body" was called with all its contents sent to the characters() method). so, don't expect events for each tag--make sure you rewrite all content in characters() too